# Excel 2016 upgrade causing a memory crash

Tags: excel, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, excel-2016, vba

I came back from vacation to see all of my Excel applications crash after a few seconds/minutes of running.  With the new upgrade to 2016, there seems to be some weird behavior.

For example, the below works totally fine

```
Sub Test1()
  for i = 1 to 10000000
    temp1 = 4 + 6
  next i
End Sub
```

The following, however, causes my excel to crash in a couple of seconds as the memory needed in my TaskManager just keeps climbing to over 1.5GB

```
Sub Test2()
  for i = 1 to 10000000
    temp1 = worksheetfunction.Min(5,7)
  next i
End Sub
```

I'm guessing I'll have to revert to 2013 as I have thousands of lines of code that will most likely need modification (not sure to what though)

Any ideas what could be causing this and a solution?

Thanks

Comment: It's a known bug that excel 2016 (windows) in some situations doesn't release the memory and will crash this way (sooner or later)... sometimes you only need to restart the application, but other times you need to reboot the whole system. Till a hotfix is released, we cant do anything about this... sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi sorry you are hitting this.  I have posted a workaround for the problem here.  Please let me know if that does not resolve your issue.  We will have a more permanent fix very soon.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-excel/excel-2016-macro-crashes-sometimes-gibes-an-out-of/37a7df04-9d1b-4b6b-b107-e8d0971e324e

-Tyson Murray
Excel

Answer (score 2):

> I want to let you know that the Excel team recently fixed this issue.
>   The fix is in build 16.0.6366.2062, which started rolling out on 1/25.
>   If you don't see the update yet, go to File > Account > Update Options > Update Now.

[(source)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-customize/excel-2016-runs-out-of-memory-when-calculating/d2c59e11-579c-4285-8c50-0a484921ac53)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed back a few months ago and today I see 2 memory leaks.  It's back!

Microsoft updated last night... Jun 14/2016

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, it is not an answer